# How can I get the Flutter app to display SVG images where `href` is used?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, href

I would like to display SVG images in my Flutter app, but they don't show up because I use `href` in it.
Is there any way to display these SVG images in this case?
By the way, we are already using `flutter_svg`.

By the way, this is how `href` is used.

```
<use xlink:href="#image0_11_2222" transform="scale(0.00100000 0.00200000)"/>
```

```
<image id="image0_11_2222" width="300" height="300" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,
...
```

By the way, if I remove the part where `href` is used, the application is no longer normal.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use svg images as asset or as url you need to add [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) plugin, this plugin provide many utilities for svg pictures

1. For Network svg image

```
final Widget networkSvg = SvgPicture.network(
  'https://site-that-takes-a-while.com/image.svg',
  semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
);
```

2.For Asset Image

```
final String assetName = 'assets/up_arrow.svg';
final Widget svgIcon = SvgPicture.asset(
                     assetName,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.srcIn),
            semanticsLabel: 'A red up arrow'
               );
```

3.From base 64 string you can use your svg tag directly as shown below

```
SvgPicture.string(
                '''<svg viewBox="...">...</svg>''' 
            )
```

by the way xlink:href is deprecated but still you want to use them you can use it by below method.

```
<use xlink:href="#image0_11_2222" href = “#image0_11_2222” transform="scale(0.00100000 0.00200000)"/>

<image id="image0_11_2222" width="300" height="300" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64
```

use href along with xlink:href in the use tag, you can refer [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) for more info

Comment: I would like to use that package to display it, but apparently I can't if the `href` tag is used in the SVG image.

Comment: Check I've updated my answer for string as well and also can you please share me the svg image code ?

Comment: I checked the updated text, but it does not seem to describe a solution, as it does not describe the specific wording of what to do. Please check my question text again.

Comment: You can check the updated answer , if it get help!!!